# Is it true that $\int_a^b\big[\;f(x)-\int_a^b f(\xi) d\xi\;\big]dx=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\int_a^b\big[\;f(x)-\int_a^b f(\xi) d\xi\;\big]dx=0$$

Is this fact true?

I think yes, it is sufficient ti change $x$ with $\xi$.

Is it correct? Thank you

Comment: Notice that the LHS is $(1-b+a) \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx$. So the equation does not hold if $b-a \neq 1$ and $ \int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx \neq 0$.

Comment: It is not true...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is wrong, try with simple functions :

$f(x)=1, a=0, b=2$ gives you $-2$

But it is true that $$\int_a^b\left(f(x)-\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b{f(u)du}\right)=0$$

Answer (score 9):

Using the linearity of the integral, we can deduce
$$
\int_a^b\left[\;f(x)-\int_a^b f(\xi) d\xi\;\right]dx=\int_a^bf(x)~dx-\int_a^b\int_a^bf(\xi)~d\xi~dx\\=\int_a^bf(x)~dx-(b-a)\int_a^bf(\xi)~d\xi
$$
So you get
$$
\int_a^b\left[\;f(x)-\int_a^b f(\xi) d\xi\;\right]dx=0\Leftrightarrow \int_a^bf(x)~dx=(b-a)\int_a^bf(\xi)~d\xi
$$
You see, the statement is true if either $b-a=1$ or $\int_a^bf(x)~dx=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, a counterexample. When $\text{f}\left(x\right):=\sin\left(x\right)$:

$$\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\left\{\sin\left(x\right)-\int_\text{a}^\text{b}\sin\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t\right\}\space\text{d}x=\left(1+\text{a}-\text{b}\right)\cdot\left(\cos\left(\text{a}\right)-\cos\left(\text{b}\right)\right)\tag1$$